# How to retrieve an environment texture (MTLTexture) cubeMap and change to Spherical Harmonics

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, metal, texture-mapping

I would like to save the auto-generated environment texture from an `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`, and then load that same texture later into a different tracking configuration to be added to a model. How is this done?

I have looked through everything I could find online and looked through Apple's documentation thoroughly (ideally I would like to accomplish this without getting too deep into Metal). Getting stuck currently on `MTLTexture.Protocol`.

This is what Apple's documentation provides: 
 `var environmentTexture: MTLTexture? { get }`

Was originally thinking to use something like this to retrieve the texture, though it doesn't work:

```
var environmentTexture: MTLTexture? {
       get {
           var envTextCube = self.environmentTexture
           if envTextCube == MTLTexture.addSomethingHere {
               print("Succesfully returned environment cube texture (auto)!")
               return envTextCube
           }
           else {
               return nil
           }
       }
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you plan to do with the environment texture (or equivalent spherical harmonics coefficients) once you load it back from disk? Since the `environmentTexture` property of ARKit light probe anchors is read-only, you won't be able to set your deserialized environment on a probe that's being tracked by ARKit. You could perhaps use such a texture as the lighting environment of a SceneKit scene or use it for custom rendering with Metal; is that closer to your intention?

Comment: The plan was to use the texture as lighting on a model oriented in the ARFaceTrackingConfiguration (a workaround due to the default constraints). The thought being that if the environmentTexture was captured just before launching ARFace, then the lighting reflections would be accurate (on say the lenses of glasses) after some linear algebra. Would this need a custom render pipeline?

Comment: I think so, currently. I tried converting an ARKit-captured environment map into SceneKit through a fairly convoluted process (`MTLTexture`->`CGImage`->`MDLLightProbe`->`SCNLight`), but it seems that SceneKit doesn't currently support creating a `.probe`-type light from an `MDLLightProbe`. But what you want is certainly possible with Metal.

Comment: Note that you may find it easier to retrieve the lighting estimate while the face-tracking session is running, since you can get an approximate set of spherical harmonics coordinates from the `lightEstimate` property of each `ARFrame` (during a face-tracking sessions, the `lightEstimate` property returns an object of type `ARDirectionalLightEstimate`). These are used automatically by SceneKit when enabled, but you can also use them in, e.g., a custom Metal rendering pipeline.

Comment: Completely agree the direct lighting estimation is easier, and I tried that first :) The main problem I saw was there is a lot less detail provided (ie. no specific colors) which would be needed for realistic reflections. That said, in theory could certainly be used in conjunction with the altered MTLTexture to adjust the overall intensity of the applied lighting.